# Laptop keyboard stopped working on both Windows and Ubuntu after Ubuntu update

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard

I installed ubuntu 20.04 LTS for the first time on my laptop a couple of hours ago and when I finished the setup everything was working perfectly fine. I was going to install some apps such as chrome and discord but ubuntu showed a message for an update and I decided to do it after I finish downloading.

So after I finished downloading, I went back to settings and downloaded the update then I clicked reboot. After the reboot my keyboard was not working at both login and desktop screens.

Then I booted back to windows (dual boot) and my keyboard was not working in windows too.
I checked windows device manager and my keyboard was not showing up. So i checked show hidden devices box and the keyboard was there but it was saying that the drivers were not completely installed (error code 24). I tried checking for drivers but windows couldn't find one. On the Ubuntu end I don't know what to do.

p.s: External keyboard via USB is working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a coincidence. There's nothing that could have happened in Ubuntu that would have affected the keyboard in Windows

Answer (score 0):

Is your internal keyboard working in BIOS? If not, I personally think the cable might have come loose somehow.

If yes try these :

Can your check your `xinput --list` output and see if keyboard is showing up there ?

you can try these commands as well

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all

startx
```

Comment: It's not working in BIOS too. I don't think it's because of the cable since the keyboard lights up. I also found out it works for a few seconds when i boot up.